# Why the ImportContactsRequest (telethon 1.3) method does not add contacts and does not generate an error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telethon

ImportContactsRequest method (telethon 1.3). Adding a new contact by phone number does not work. Is it possible to change this method to another?

```
async def fing():
    guest_phone_number = '+7XXXXXXXXX'
    client = TelegramClient("sessionname",api_id = XXXXXXX, api_hash = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX').start()
    client.connect()
    contact = InputPhoneContact(client_id=0, phone=guest_phone_number, 
first_name="custom_first_name", last_name="custom_last_name")
    client(ImportContactsRequest([contact]))
    getContacts = telethon.tl.functions.contacts.GetContactsRequest(0)
    Contacts = client(getContacts)
    print(Contacts.stringify().find('+7ХХХХХХХХХ'))
    client.disconnect()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop2 = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop2.run_until_complete(fing())
```

Comment: I looked through a lot of questions about this issue, but I can't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: 2 possible issue: first: make sure that your guest_phone_number has telegram account, second: you may have reached the rate limit of calling ImportContactsRequest API.

Comment: yes this number has an account in telegram

Comment: about the second way. Do you mean that I have sent too many contacts at once or my contact list is full?

Comment: Or does the call to ImportContactsRequest not complete in this program? Please explain what you mean.

Comment: each Telegram API has its own rate limit, and if you go beyond that limit, you may get floodlimit error, but in ImportContactsRequest you just get an empty reply and nothing will be added to your contacts list. (Telegram pays a lot of attention to users' privacy) ... it means that you may have called that API several times(in a short period of time).

Comment: I correctly understood that this method sends an invitation to contacts and has a limit on the number of possible messages. Will he appear in my contacts when he answers?

Comment: Could there be a problem because the application is not yet official?

Comment: Importing contacts is just like adding a number to phone's contacts list and there is no "invitaion" in this action. Have you tried to check the result of your API call? result = client(ImportContactsRequest([contact])). Then print out the result and check if there is useful info

Comment: Yes, I tried  ImportedContacts(imported=[], popular_invites=[PopularContact(client_id=0, importers=182)], retry_contacts=[], users=[])

Comment: Is there a similar method to replace? Maybe this method does not work.